# TreeView not showing second level children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

XAML goes like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- templates -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ProjectSteps" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ProjectsOverview" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectSteps}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectsOverview}">
</TreeView>
```

Projects is a property on my ViewModel, and it comes from this class:

```
public class ProjectsRepository : IProjectsRepository {
    public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects() {
        return new List<Project> {
            new Project {
                Name = "Proj1",
                Steps = new List<Step> {
                    new Step { Name = "Step1" },
                    new Step { Name = "Step2" },
                    new Step { Name = "Step3" }
                }
            },
            new Project {
                Name = "Proj2",
                Steps = new List<Step> {
                    new Step { Name = "OtherStep1" },
                    new Step { Name = "OtherStep2" },
                    new Step { Name = "OtherStep3" },
                    new Step { Name = "OtherStep4" }
                }
            } };
    }
}
```

First level items (Proj1, Proj2) are displayed, but the second level items (so each Step or OtherStep) are not. I can't even see the dropdown indicator next to the project name, so it seems that the second `ProjectSteps` template is not rendered anywhere. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of in ProjectSteps set ItemsSource in ProjectsOverview

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ProjectsOverview" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
```